# Data Driven Selenium with TFS

Tags: selenium, tfs, automated-tests, tfs-2015

I am trying to get Selenium to be Data Driven with Microsoft TFS. I understand Selenium IDE but from what I've researched Selenium IDE cannot be used with a data driven format. What I'm trying to have the data driven section do is cycle through the repositories and add different TFS team and permissions to them. I can set up what I want in Selenium IDE but have no idea how to make it data driven with an excel sheet. Here is my HTML Source Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://MyTFS/" />
<title>DragAndDropPrologue</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">DragAndDropPrologue</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/tfs/DefaultCollection/XO/_build</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>6000</td>
    <td>6000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>//label[text()=&quot;Repo1;]/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=Edit</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=//span[text()='Add build step...']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=(//button[@value='Add'])[11]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=(//button[@value='Add'])[12]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=ok</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>dragAndDropToObject</td>
    <td>//div[text()=&quot;Fetch the Quality Profile from SonarQube&quot;]/</td>
    <td>//div[text()=&quot;Ant&quot;]/</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>css=div.wrap &gt; input[type=&quot;text&quot;]</td>
    <td>Sonar</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=projectKey</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=projectName</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>dragAndDropToObject</td>
    <td>//div[text()=&quot;SonarQube for MSBuild - End Analysis&quot;]/</td>
    <td>//div[text()=&quot;Ant&quot;]/</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=//span[text()='Save']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=ok</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>//label[text()=&quot;Repo2;]/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=Edit</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=//span[text()='Add build step...']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=(//button[@value='Add'])[11]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=(//button[@value='Add'])[12]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=ok</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>dragAndDropToObject</td>
    <td>//div[text()=&quot;Fetch the Quality Profile from SonarQube&quot;]/</td>
    <td>//div[text()=&quot;Ant&quot;]/</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>css=div.wrap &gt; input[type=&quot;text&quot;]</td>
    <td>Sonar</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=projectKey</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=projectName</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>dragAndDropToObject</td>
    <td>//div[text()=&quot;SonarQube for MSBuild - End Analysis&quot;]/</td>
    <td>//div[text()=&quot;Ant&quot;]/</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=//span[text()='Save']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=ok</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Surely there is an API for TFS to do this directly rather than automating the UI, yes? Have you looked?

Comment: According to your description, you want to make data driven with an excel sheet in Selenium IDE, so your query is actually not related to TFS, correct? If your query is related to TFS, would you specify what you want to achieve on TFS side?

Comment: Check this blog to see whether it is helpful: https://unmesh.me/2012/12/04/data-driven-testing-with-selenium-ide/

Comment: So you want to configure the repository permission automatically?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT that worked perfectly thank you